# Flutter Stack with background image and form

Tags: android, ios, flutter, stack, widget

I have a screen where the background image is set to fill the whole screen and on top of that, there are input fields. When I click on TextFormField, the keyboard is shown and the background image is pushed to the top, which is the behaviour I do not want to.

Do you know how not top push image up? I think Form (with SingleChildScrollView) widget is rendered on top of the screen (index > that backgroundImage), so I do not understand why the image is deformed. Any ideas?

Code:

```
   class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Image.asset("imageAsset",
                     fit: BoxFit.fitWidth),
            ),
            SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Form(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    FormField(), // Example
                    FormField(), // Example
                    FormField(), // Example
                  ]),
            )
          ],
        )));
      }
    }
```

Comment: Try setting  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false in your scaffold

Comment: I tried it, but then the keyboard is over third FormField() and you can't see the text.

Answer (score 0):

Use TextFormField and I recommend using ListView instead of singleChildScrollView.

```
class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
    body: Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Image.asset("imageAsset", fit: BoxFit.fill),
    ),
    ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Form(
          child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                TextFormField(), // Example
                TextFormField(), // Example
                TextFormField(), // Example
              ]),
        ),
      ],
    )
  ],
  ));
  }
  }
```